# Combining two different validation in SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I need to combine two different validation formula in SharePoint list.

For example, The two different "IF" formula needs to be put in 1 validation setting in the SharePoint list. Do I use AND in between?

IF([Issue Status]<>"draft,IF(COUNTA([Error]),1,false,true),IF(COUNTA([Error])=1,TRUE,TRUE))

IF(AND([Cross Exposure]="yes",ISBLANK([Exposure Type 2])),FALSE,TRUE)

**Cross Exposure is a drop down field "yes" or "no" . It defaults to "No"

Thanks!

Comment: What your specific requirement for validation? Under which condition is true? Under which condition is false?

Comment: so the two formula works independently but i want o put them in one validation.

Comment: Due to these two formulas work independently, put them in one validation is not available.